# I can't seem to be able to use hooks in react

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-hooks

I'm starting a new react app. So far, nothing weird has been added. This is how my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "fibers": "^5.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.0",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-thunk": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Then I try the most simple of react hooks call within a component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Gallery = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(null);
  return <div>Gallery</div>;
};

export default Gallery;
```

But when I try to run it, I get:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
>   of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
>   reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html for tips about how to debug and
>   fix this problem.

The package.json seems to be ok. No duplicate react versions. React is 16.8+. And the component is a functional component, not a class-based one. What could I be missing?

NOTE: When I try to run the "npm ls react" suggested in the documentation, I get no versions listed. react-dom appears correctly. Could this be the cause? And if so, any ideas of how to fix it?

Comment: Is this your only component? If you have others, did you check all of them?

Comment: `package.json` says `"react": "^16.13.1",` which is not necessarily `React 16.8.0`. I would change your react dependency to exactly `React 16.8.0` to see if that makes a difference. For good measure, be sure to run `rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install` after your update your `package.json`.

Comment: Previous comment is useful; also, are your React and ReactDOM packages on the same version? Check your lockfile and see.

Answer (score 1):

- Problem, can be using different version of react & react-dom dependencies
- If you are using react-router-dom and have Routes like this

  ```
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} exact /> 
          <Route path="/gallery" render={Gallery} exact />
        </Switch>
     </Router>
   );
  ```

Here, instead of `<Route path="/gallery" render={Gallery} exact />` use this `<Route path="/gallery" component={Gallery} />`

That, solved my problem

Comment: I had the same problem & I spend hours solving it, this answer magically works for me. Thanks a lot